# Make custom textfield autocomplete compatible with slashes?

Tags: forms, ajax, 7

I have a form which uses a textfield with a custom autocomplete path and it works just as it should. However, I get some unexpected behavior when the title/search string contains a backslash (e.g. '10/07/2016 Meeting').

After some investigation I realized that Drupal seems to interpret those as 4 separate parameters with only the first (in this case 10) being passed to the autocomplete function.  I'm not sure how I can prevent this behaviour as the passing of the string to the form is handled internally by Drupal via the `'#autocomplete_path'` on the textfield itself.

I checked how entity reference handled this, but it is using an entirely custom field and not the `'#autocomplete_path'` on a regular textfield and wasn't of much use to me.

However it would seem odd to me that the textfield autocomplete shouldn't be able to support search strings with slashes - I just can't find out how to hook into the Drupal form to encode the string somehow.

How can I make my autocomplete field compatible with slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a cue from the Drupal core's [taxonomy autocomplete implementation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.pages.inc?h=7.50#n122) and just recombine the arguments passed into callback function back into one string:

```
function taxonomy_autocomplete($field_name = '', $tags_typed = '') {

  // If the request has a '/' in the search text, then the menu system will have
  // split it into multiple arguments, recover the intended $tags_typed.
  $args = func_get_args();
  // Shift off the $field_name argument.
  array_shift($args);
  $tags_typed = implode('/', $args);
```

Comment: Seems I was too fixed on checking modules like entity reference that I forgot looking at taxomomy. func_get_args() totally did the trick. Thanks!